# How can I pass parameters to python?

Tags: python, mod-python

The python parameter is not passed.

I think cgi.FieldStorage () does not seem to work.
What settings should I add?

cgi.html :

```
<form action="cgi.py" method="get">
First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name">  <br />

Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

cgi.py :

```
# Import modules for CGI handling
import cgi, cgitb
cgitb.enable()

# Create instance of FieldStorage
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# Get data from fields
first_name = form.getvalue('first_name')
last_name  = form.getvalue('last_name')

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - Second CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>Hello %s %s</h2>" % (first_name, last_name)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

chrome result:

[image]
apache version:

```
httpd-2.4.6-40.el7.centos.4.x86_64
python-2.7.5-48.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: No idea if it's relevant, but you're missing a `/` at the end of the first `input` tag.

Comment: You're completely confusing mod_python and CGI here. They are not the same thing at all. You don't need mod_python to run CGI programs via Python; the CGIHandler class in mod_python is explicitly there ["as a stepping stone for the migration of legacy code away from CGI"](http://modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/handlers.html#cgi-handler), it is not for writing new CGI services in. (Actually, you shouldn't be writing new CGI services *at all*, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: We were well aware of the association between cgi and mod_python. But the above problem still can not be solved. I want to be successful in parameter passing. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using If else condition while you call
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

Apart from that, code and formatting look good to me. However, you can go through a simple tutorial as below. This will help you to fill the values from a form and will look something like this
value = form.getlist(" ")

Ref: https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgi.html